incomplete table borders, truncated, watertight
The borders around the following (relatively simple) table are incomplete/truncated.   What am I missing to make this table look more 'watertight' and professional?
\begin{tabular} {|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 
\toprule
\centering\textbf{Feature} & \centering\textbf{MRR}  \tabularnewline
\midrule
Heuristic only & 0.59    \tabularnewline\hline
Heuristic with QACES & 0.63   \tabularnewline\hline
Percentage change & +6.8\% \tabularnewline

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}



Don't use vertical lines if you use the booktabs package. Either make a professional looking table without vertical lines or make a "watertight" table by removing the booktabs package. They are mutually exclusive.

I also advocate removing vertical rules. Simply because well designed tables can speak by themselves without any unnecessary additions.
However, there is a way to merge horizontal and even vertical lines of different thickness if you load array package. You just change | and \hline to custom definitions, s.a. !{...} and \noalign{...}, respectively (more info here.)
The example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.35}
    \begin{tabular}{|
            >{\raggedright}p{3cm} !{\vrule width 0.8pt}
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |
        } 
        \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
        \centering\textbf{Feature} & \textbf{MRR} \\\noalign{\hrule height 0.5pt}
        Heuristic only             & 0.59         \\\hline
        Heuristic with QACES       & 0.63         \\\hline
        Percentage change          & +6.8\%       \\\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



Don't use vertical rules along with the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package. Actually, don't use vertical rules at all -- trust me, they won't be missed.
Here's an excerpt from section 2 of the user guide of the booktabs package:



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {@{} 
          >{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}p{3cm} % automatic hanging indentation
          c 
          @{}} 
  \toprule
  \textbf{Feature}     & \textbf{MRR} \\
  \midrule
  Heuristic only       & 0.59    \\
  Heuristic with QACES & 0.63    \\
  Percentage change    & +6.8\%  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Thanks Mico - that looks very professional.   On mature reflection, I agree that vertical lines are not helpful to the flow of the presentation of the table.

If you actually want to use vertical rules with booktabs (which is not at all in the spirit of booktabs), you can use {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular} {|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 
\toprule
\centering\textbf{Feature} & \centering \textbf{MRR} \tabularnewline
\midrule
Heuristic only & 0.59   \\
Heuristic with QACES & 0.63  \\
Percentage change & +6.8\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



Thanks @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz
You put me in the right direction, but I couldn't remove the booktabs package without breaking 'other' tables in my document.
I've remove the toprule/midrule/bottomrule (part of the booktabs package) and replace them with a simple hline: -
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\centering\textbf{Feature} & \centering\textbf{MRR}  \tabularnewline
\hline
Heuristic only & 0.57 $\pm$ 0.12    \\
Heuristic with QACES & 0.60 $\pm$ 0.12  \\
Percentage change & +5.3\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

This produces: -


Why not forego the unneeded vertical rules?

@Colin If you have some time, consider reading some of the books by Edward Tufte for an in-depth explanation why tables are better off without vertical lines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte#Works_of_analytic_design
